# How to create Hemi sync, mediative music?

Tags: logic-pro, how-to

**EDIT:**

I have a great desire to create meditative music that use binaural beats, alpha waves, delta wave, etc. in the style of Kip Mazuy, Christopher Lloyd Clarke, and other composers known in that genre.

We do have a MBP with LogicPro, but I am not certain how I can use the basic software in order to create these beats. Can you help explain how this is possible, or advise me of a resource that can help?

> **OP-** I have huge desire creation of mediative music as such style probably here not to pick up, but more or less the close at what I aim, this creativity of Kip Mazuy, Christopher Lloyd Clarke (that that like Brainwave, alpha wave, delta wave, binaural sounds) and many other composers known in the circles, but I couldn't find a material in this style, on a YouTube, in the main video about bouhm bouhm bouhm and other modern bit "art". That do we have, we have MBP with LogicPro, which that already I know, but not how it would be desirable, can you give that to advise in this direction what to esteem or to whom to address? 
>   Sorry for my bad english))

Answer (score 1):

I've done an esotheric meditative music project in the past using Gnaural free brainwave generator with Omnisphere. Frequency of a binaural beats was selected in the respect to a desired effect (hence you need to dig the basics of brainwaves and corresponding sounds) + all other sounds were chosen in order to stimulate targeted state. Each track consisted of nature elements like fire, water wind etc, strings and harp for heart stimulation and low bass rumble for meditation state (something like throat singing). I'd suggest to make a plan what you want to achieve, then research which way sonically you could do that. Logic is powerful and once you know what you want its easy to make using factory tools and maybe some freeware.

As for some examples - check out David Parsons

Comment: Thanks for Gnaural, but it a little bit not that, I wanted to use only factory tools of Logic. Do you have any advice? 
thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Before you spend took much time on binural beats, you should take a listen to this:
[skeptoid.com/episodes/4147](http://skeptoid.com/episodes/4147)
Click "listen" under the headline to get the podcast version.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your care, but I'm interested in not only the binaural beats and sounds in the style Hemi sinc, DNA, Solfeggio, and not just monotonal sounds, but like composition, such as in the video below http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKSFvJGODKI Let's leave useless trolling about the benefits, but just think about how you can create something similar, using Logic pro.
 Thanks and regards, always your dbx.